# Pass a Put or a Delete. Hbase and Hadoop

Tags: java, hbase

I am quite new with hadoop and hbase. However, I have tested my Hbase and Hadoop is working. I am stuck with error msg Pass a put or a Delete. My Map phase reads few text lines from hbase table "dsite" and pass them to Reducer which should just write them to different table. No matter what I do, I always get that same "Pass a put or a Delete"..

Examples Ive been watching doesnt help .. I dont use iterable or Iterator etc.

Any tips would be fine ..

My code is:

```
static class Mapper12 extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>
{
    public void mapper(ImmutableBytesWritable row,Result valuess,Context context) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            context.write(row,valuess);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static class Reducer12 extends TableReducer<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put, ImmutableBytesWritable>
{
    public void reducer(ImmutableBytesWritable key,Put values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Put put = new Put();

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("url"), Bytes.toBytes("www"),Bytes.toBytes(values.toString()));
        context.write(key,put);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mapper outputs a key-value pair of type
`ImmutableBytesWritable -> Result` but your Reducer reads in a key-value pair of type `ImmutableBytesWritable -> Put`. This can't work as the output of the mapper must be of the same type the input of the reducer is. You should either

- change your mapper to output a `Put` object and adjust your method and class signatures
- or change the reducer signatures to allow for a Result object as in-value.